# AngularJS - Can I remove images from ng-bind-html's property by not manipulating core HTML content?

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

I want to not to show images in my html content which is rendered by ng-bind-html directive. How can I do this?

```
<div ng-bind-html="news.body"></div>
```

Here I want to remove the images from "news.body" content. By not manipulating the core HTML content.

Is it possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample code would help. It seems obvious - remove the images from the expression you're binding to the `ng-bind-html` directive.

Comment: @BernhardHofmann is my question not clear to you? I think there is no need to sample code here. I do not want to show images into ng-bind-html rendered html by not doing any manipulation in core html. However I am adding sample code here